# Get objects from sql which have no associated objects with specific field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I have Job and Feedback models.

They are associated like this:

`Job has_many :feedbacks
Feedback belongs_to :job`

I'm trying to make a query to get jobs which have NO feedbacks with `feedback.user_id == job.client_id`

Comment: Paste the code what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @user123 `jobs_as_worker = current_user.jobs_as_worker.includes(:feedbacks).where{client_id.not_in Feedback.select{user_id}.uniq}`

Answer (score 1):

```
 jobs=Job.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT id', :order=>"id asc").map { |n| n.id.to_s })
 feedbacks=Feedback.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT job_id', :order=>"job_id asc").map { |n| n.job_id.to_s })
 jobs_without_feedbacks=jobs-feedbacks
```

ok. then try this. it might work good in your case.
jobs_without_feedbacks will be the array of ids of the job with no feedback.

Comment: I don't need `jobs` without ANY `feedbacks`. 

I need `jobs` without `feedbacks` with `user_id == job.client_id`.

If job has feedbacks with any other `user_id` – it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs=Job.all
no_feedback_jobs=Array.new
jobs.each do |job|{ (no_feedback_jobs<< job) if !job.feedback}
```

Try this .It will work fine

Comment: That works but I want to do it in the database, because it will be very slow if I have a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
feedbacks = Feedback.map(&:user_id).uniq

User.includes(:jobs => :feedbacks).where.not(:client_id => feedbacks).where(:id => current_user.id)
```

Try this

Comment: I suppose this is the same.

`jobs_as_worker = current_user.jobs_as_worker.includes(:feedbacks).where{client_id.not_in Feedback.select{user_id}.uniq}`

This code works but not in the way I need. I need to use not all feedbacks in databse – `Feedback.select{user_id}.uniq`, but feedbacks only for a specific job, like `jobs.feedbacks.select{user_id}.uniq` – but I can't make this work.

Comment: No, I want jobs which have NO feedbacks with `feedback.user_id == job.client_id`

Comment: Then in your code why you have written 
current_user.jobs_as_worker?

Comment: I want `jobs` that belong to `current_user`

Comment: I was asking the same question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78796/discussion-between-user123-and-vladzaets).

Comment: I didn't ask any questions.

I need current_user's jobs which DON'T have feedbacks with specific user_id. Any other user_id's are ok.

Answer (score 0):

This uses two queries, but the `pluck` should be relatively light.

```
Job.includes(:feedbacks)
  .where(feedbacks: {id: nil})
  .where.not(client_id: Feedback.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: What `.where(feedbacks: {id: nil})` means? How `id` could be `nil`?

Comment: `Job.includes(:feedbacks).where(feedbacks: {id: nil}` returns jobs which do not have feedbacks.

Comment: This query returns Jobs where its client has feedbacks. I need Jobs where it's client didn't get feedback for this specific job.

Comment: I need something like this: `.includes(:feedbacks).where(feedbacks: {id: nil}).where.not(feedbacks: {user_id: job.client_id})` – but I can't make it work.

Comment: How about adding a `not` to the last line?

Comment: It returns only 1 job, but I expect to get 3. That is because of `Feedback.pluck(:user_id)`. I need to use something like `job.feedbacks.pluck(:user_id)` but I don't know if it is possible